# Minimize tile overlay calls during zoom or pan

Tags: ios, maps, apple-maps

I have a map view where I am overlaying tiles from a map-guide server. The `MKTileOverlay` method `URLForTilePath` gets called on every zoom or pan action from the user.
Suppose the user is zooming in/out by say 3 to 4 levels, the `URLForTilePath` in `MKTileOverlay` get called at each of the intermediate zoom levels. Since fetching images for tiles is costly, I want to avoid calling the overlay methods till the user has stopped zooming.

My current thinking is:

1. Stop MapView from auto rendering tiles upon zoom or pan
2. Detect that map / pan has stopped
3. Trigger overlay process manually after #2 above

Questions:

- Is this approach any better or are there other ways of doing it?
- Is the cost of removing and adding overlays less than the cost of
  fetching tiles for each zoom or pan?
- If I go with above approach, how do I detect that map / pan function has stopped?

We can assume that the interval for a bunch of zoom or pan actions to be considered together is say 2 seconds.
On every zoom or pan `regionWillChangeAnimated` / `regionDidChangeAnimated` gets called. I need a way to execute only the last call of `regionDidChangeAnimated` if it occurs within a space of say 2 seconds.

Sample code: MapViewController

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)    overlay
{
    return [[MKTileOverlayRenderer alloc] initWithTileOverlay:overlay];;
}
- (void)addLayer:(NSString *)layer
{
    Tile *overlay = [[Tile alloc] init];
    overlay.canReplaceMapContent = NO;
    overlay.layerName = layer;
    [mapView addOverlay:overlay level:MKOverlayLevelAboveLabels];
}
```

Sample code: Tile

```
@interface Tile : MKTileOverlay
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *layerName;
@end

@implementation Tile
@synthesize layerName;

- (NSURL *)URLForTilePath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path
{    
    return [NSURL URLWithString:@"Url with tile coordinates and layerName"];
}
@end
```

Thanks!